# How could I add some attribute of a pop-up window from the parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a pop-up window opened by the following from the parent page:

```
popitup("foobar.html");

function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=700,width=1000');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

After the page is popped up, I want to add the following to the **body tag** of the pop-up

```
<body onunload="window.opener.parent.location.reload();">
```

How could I reach out and do such modification from the parent window? Do I have to include such code in a function that runs after the pop-up is loaded?

thanks!

P.S. all pages are in the same domain. I want to do the modification after the pop up is loaded.

I understand there is some function that could run after an iframe is loaded, could such function also be applied to a pop up in some variance way?

```
jQuery("#ifrm").load( function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without jQuery,

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=700,width=1000');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    newwindow.onload = function(){
        newwindow.document.body.onunload = function(){
            window.opener.parent.location.reload();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
popitup("/");
```